# SeekBar inside another class

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have created a SeekBar that displays distance. This distance is used in order to show a circle with a specific distance as its radius.

In my `onCreate` I have the following lines:

```
SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.sb_radius);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
```

Then, the class where I use it is as follows:

```
   private void Search_Map(float dpWidth, float dpHeight, Object Lat, Object Lon) {

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // updated continuously as the user slides the thumb
            tvDistance.setText( "Progress: " + progress );
            Show_Map(dpWidth, dpHeight, Lat, Lon, progress*1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // called when the user first touches the SeekBar
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // called after the user finishes moving the SeekBar
        }
    };
}
```

My problem is that it never does any action because I'm getting an error at my `onCreate` saying:

```
cannot resolve symbol seekBarChangeListener.
```

How can I use the seekbar inside my class and yet to make the listener work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);` line from `onCreate` and add it to end of `Search_Map`

```java
class ClassName{
Seekerbar seekerbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.sb_radius);

}
private void Search_Map(float dpWidth, float dpHeight, Object Lat, Object Lon) {

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // updated continuously as the user slides the thumb
            tvDistance.setText( "Progress: " + progress );
            Show_Map(dpWidth, dpHeight, Lat, Lon, progress*1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // called when the user first touches the SeekBar
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // called after the user finishes moving the SeekBar
        }
    };
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

} 
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Now im getting "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(android.widget.SeekBar$OnSeekBarChangeListener)' on a null object reference"

Comment: You have to define Seekerbar out side the `onCreate`.

Comment: Updated answer. Check that